# how to get the columns number when user clicks on adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have Gridlayout inside my recycled view adapter.
I want to know how can I get the column number when the user clicks on the item inside the adapter. For example, my grid layout has 3 columns, when the user clicks on row number one columns number 3, I want to get 3

Comment: How do you populate the adapter?

Comment: you can use getRowCount() on your GridLayout to get the number of the rows, and when any item is clicked you take the position of the Item you can use this formula     `columnNum = position % getRowCount()`  note that the column always start from zero if you want it to start from 1 then add 1 to the equation above

Comment: the calculation above is not going to work. I have 3 columns of grid layout. position 6 is going to be on column number 3 row 2.  6%2 = 0

Comment: the answer is positioned % total Column numbers.

Comment: Just use columnNum = position-1 % getRowCount()

Answer (score 0):

Using modulo is a good way to go about it.

So inside the onClickListener:

```
int numColumns = yourGridView.getColumnCount();
if(position % numColumns == 0){
//item is in the first column
} else if(position % numColumns == 1){
//item is in second column
} else if(position % numColumns == 2){
//item is in third column
}...
```

This picture below illustrates how arrayList positions can be translated into columns positions in the case of three columns (modulo 3):

[image]

Thanks